# Make navigation drawer close for the first time run

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have an app with navigation drawer. Everything works good, however my navigation drawer opens automatically as my app starts.

I do not want to see my navigation drawer unless I swipe of click to menu button.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your code, without code we can not tell you where you did wrong.

Comment: According to Design Guideline (https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction), navigation drawer open in first run is preferable because it show user that there is something on the side. 
To disable it though, you have to put up some code. I think it is saved in SharedPreference.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the navigation drawer activity. Make sure it has been already opened.

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
... 
if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
  //drawer is open 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `YourDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();` in your main activity, on `OnCreate` method, to close navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

For closing..

```
private void closeDrawer() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
}
```